# next-auth | GithubProvider error=OAuthCallback

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using **nextAuth** and also I'm working with **GithubProvider**. I just got an error in my vsCode terminal :

[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error client_secret_basic client authentication method requires a client_secret {
**error: TypeError: client_secret_basic client authentication method requires a client_secret**
at Client.authFor (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\openid-client\lib\helpers\client.js:143:15)
at Client.authenticatedPost (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\openid-client\lib\helpers\client.js:182:30)
at Client.grant (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:1343:46)
at Client.oauthCallback (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\openid-client\lib\client.js:620:35)
at oAuthCallback (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\next-auth\core\lib\oauth\callback.js:111:29)
at async Object.callback (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\next-auth\core\routes\callback.js:52:11)
at async AuthHandler (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\next-auth\core\index.js:208:28)
at async NextAuthApiHandler (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:22:19)
at async NextAuth._args$ (C:\Users\cmos\Desktop\moslemi-phone\node_modules\next-auth\next\index.js:108:14) {
name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
code: undefined
},
providerId: 'github',
**message: 'client_secret_basic client authentication method requires a client_secret'**
}

I couldn't find the solution and I will welcome all your help and idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here are a few steps you try to solve it :**

1. Make sure you have provided the correct client secret for your GitHub OAuth application.
2. Ensure that you are using the latest versions of NextAuth, and Next.js.
3. Enable debug logs for NextAuth to get more detailed information about the authentication process.

   ```
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
   ```

Comment: thanks , I just fix my client secret and its working. <3